# BMI Calculator Pythonapplied for a list

Tags: python, list, function

I created a BMI and MB calculator and everything is working fine! But now, I would like to apply this calculator to a list a patient and show result for all of them. How could I apply this a list?

Here is my code; hope you'll understand it even if there is some French aha!

```
 patients = {1: {"nom_patient":"Olivier", "sexe_patient":'H', "age_patient":35, "poids_patient":78, "taille_patient":1.85},2: 
            {"nom_patient":"Claire", "sexe_patient":'F', "age_patient":28, "poids_patient":64, "taille_patient":1.74},3: 
            {"nom_patient":"Damien", "sexe_patient":'H', "aage_patient":65, "poids_patient":89, "taille_patient":1.71}};

def calcul_imc(poids, taille):
    return poids/(taille**2)

nom_patient = str(input("Entrez votre nom:"))
poids_patient = int(input("Entrez votre poids en kg:"))
taille_patient = float(input("Entrez votre taille en m:"))
age_patient = int(input("Entrez votre age:"))
sexe_patient = str(input("Êtes-vous un homme ou une femme? (H/F)"))


imc = calcul_imc(poids_patient, taille_patient)

if imc <= 18.99:
    print("Vous êtes en maigreur, le risque de maladies est accru.")
elif imc < 24.99:
    print("Vous êtes en poids normal, le risque de maladies est faible.")
elif imc < 29.99:
    print("Vous êtes embonpoint, le risque de maladies est accru.")
else :   
    print("Vous êtes en obésité modérée, le risque de maladies est élevé.")

if sexe_patient == "H":
    sexe_patient = True
elif sexe_patient == "F":
    sexe_patient = False
else:
    print("Oupsie! L'entrée doit être Oui ou Non pour pouvoir calculer ")
    quit()
    
if sexe_patient:
    mb = 3.707*poids_patient + 492.3*taille_patient - 6.673 * age_patient + 77.607
else:
    mb = 9.740*poids_patient+172.9*taille_patient-4.737*age_patient + 667.051

print("Votre métabolisme de base est", mb)
```

Comment: Move the whole code into a function and call that function for each patient in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code in a function and use keyword argument unpacking to call the function with the right values like so:

```py
patients = {
    1: {"nom_patient":"Olivier", "sexe_patient":'H', "age_patient":35, "poids_patient":78, "taille_patient":1.85},
    2: {"nom_patient":"Claire", "sexe_patient":'F', "age_patient":28, "poids_patient":64, "taille_patient":1.74},
    3: {"nom_patient":"Damien", "sexe_patient":'H', "age_patient":65, "poids_patient":89, "taille_patient":1.71}
}
 
def calcul_imc(poids, taille):
    return poids/(taille**2)


def BMI(nom_patient, sexe_patient, age_patient, poids_patient, taille_patient):
    
    # or however you want to differentiate the patients
    print(nom_patient)

    imc = calcul_imc(poids_patient, taille_patient)

    if imc <= 18.99:
        print("Vous êtes en maigreur, le risque de maladies est accru.")
    elif imc < 24.99:
        print("Vous êtes en poids normal, le risque de maladies est faible.")
    elif imc < 29.99:
        print("Vous êtes embonpoint, le risque de maladies est accru.")
    else :   
        print("Vous êtes en obésité modérée, le risque de maladies est élevé.")

    if sexe_patient == "H":
        sexe_patient = True
    elif sexe_patient == "F":
        sexe_patient = False
    else:
        print("Oupsie! L'entrée doit être Oui ou Non pour pouvoir calculer ")
        return
    
    if sexe_patient:
        mb = 3.707*poids_patient + 492.3*taille_patient - 6.673 * age_patient + 77.607
    else:
        mb = 9.740*poids_patient+172.9*taille_patient-4.737*age_patient + 667.051
        
    print("Votre métabolisme de base est", mb)


for patient in patients.values():
    BMI(**patient)
```

Also, it might make more sense to have the patients be a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

As you stored your patient data in a dictionary, you can just iterate through it with a for loop, then run your `calcul_imc` function on every iteration:

```
for patient in patients:
    imc = calcul_imc(patients[patient]["poids_patient"], patients[patient]["taille_patient"])
```

Comment: I believe the code is missing indentation in the body of the for-loop for it to work in python.

Comment: Yeah, sorry this was my first answer ever. Thanks for correcting!